# find multiple files paths with single string

Tags: shell, batch-file

I tried to write a batch script that find all the paths of files that have the same name as the input string. right now it can find only the first file found, and i cant think of a way to make it list multiple files locations. I am not very experienced and I need some help.

this is part of the script code:

```
:start
    cls
    echo Enter file name with extension:
    set /p filename=
    echo Searching...

for %%a in (C D E F G H U W) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%"') do (
        set file=%%~nxb
        set datapath=%%~dpb\
        ::the path of the file without the filename included "C:\folder\folder\"
        set fullpath=%%b
        ::the path of the file with the filename included "C:\folder\folder\file"
        goto break
  )
)
:notfound
    cls
    echo Enter file name with extension:
    echo %filename%
    echo File Not Found!
    ping localhost -n 4 >nul
    goto start

:break
    if "%datapath:~-1%"=="\" set datapath=%datapath:~,-1%
    cls
    echo 3 %filename% found
    echo %fullpath1%
    echo %fullpath2%
    echo %fullpath3%
    --- || ---
```

I want the script to search the computer and list every encountered files with the same name and I want to be able to put those files' paths into different variables.
For example, if readme.txt is the input, then I want the list of all the paths of all the files with that specific name (readme.txt) and I want to set variable for each path so I can use it after that.

```
input:  
readme.txt

output:  
3 files found  
C:\folder\folder\readme.txt  
C:\folder\folder\folder\readme.txt  
D:\folder\readme.txt
```

Comment: `for %%a in (C D E F G H U W) do dir /s /b %%a:\%filename% 2>nul` - short enough?

Comment: yeah, its good. but the problem is that the script also have the options to copy the file or deleting it. that's why I added the fullpath and the datapath, but with that line it just list them and I can't use the paths. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set filename=readme.txt
for %%a in (C D E F G H U W) do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%"') do (
    echo you can do something here with  %%~nxb in %%~dpb
    echo    full name: %%b
  )
)
```

I see no need to set the filenames to variables, as you can process them inside your loop. But if you really need them (for some reason) in variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set filename=readme.txt
set count=0
for %%a in (C D E F G H U W) do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%" 2^>nul') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set _file[!count!]=%%b
  )
)
set _file
```

Comment: Thank you! but that solved only the length and efficiency problem... I still need help with the multiple files with the same name...

Comment: don't understand; every finding is unique (drive + path + filename + extension). If you intend to use the filename only, you should be able to find something helpful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+copy+without+overwrite).

Comment: i want the script to search the computer and list every encountered files with the same name and i want to be able to put those files' paths into different variables. for example, if readme.txt is the input, then i want the list of all the paths of all the files with that specific name (readme.txt) and i want to set variable for each path so i can use it after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code :

```dos
@echo off
Title Searching for the path with the same file name
Mode con cols=80 lines=3 & Color 9E
SET /a Count=0
set /a cnt=1
set "FileName=Readme.txt"
set "Report=%~dp0Report.txt"
set "Folder2Copy=%~dp0Readme_Folder"
set "Result2Copy=%~dp0Result2Copy.txt
If exist %Folder2Copy% RD /S /Q %Folder2Copy%
If Exist %Report% Del %Report%
If Exist %Result2Copy% Del %Result2Copy%
echo(
Echo                Searching for the path with the same file name
Rem Looking for fixed drives and store them into variables
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
For /f "skip=1" %%a IN ('wmic LOGICALDISK where driveType^=3 get deviceID') DO (
  for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
     SET /a "Count+=1"
     set "Drive[!Count!]=%%b"
   )
)

:Display
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    cls
    Title Please wait a while ... Searching for "%FileName%" on "!Drive[%%i]!\"
    echo(
    echo          Please wait a while ... Searching for "%FileName%" on "!Drive[%%i]!\" 
    Call :FindPathFile !Drive[%%i]!\ %FileName% >> %Report%
)
Start "" %Report%
Goto :AskQuestion
::***************************************************************************************
:FindPathFile <Location> <FileName>
Where.exe /r %1 %2
Goto :eof
::***************************************************************************************
:AskQuestion
cls & Mode con cols=100 lines=5
echo(
echo Did you want to make copy of all files found as name "%FileName%"
echo saved on "%Report%" ? (Y/N) ?
set /p "Input="
If /I "%INPUT%"=="Y" (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('Type "%Report%"') do (
        Call :MakeCopy "%%~i" "%Folder2Copy%\"
    )
)
Call :Explorer "%Folder2Copy%\" & exit
If /I "%INPUT%"=="N" (
        Exit
)
Goto :eof
::***************************************************************************************
:MakeCopy <Source> <Target>
If Not Exist "%~2\" MD "%~2\" (
    if not exist "%2\%~n1" ( 
    echo copying "%~1" to "%~2"
    copy /N /B "%~1" "%~2" >>%Result2Copy% 2>&1
    ) else ( 
        call :loop "%~1" "%~2"
    )
)
::***************************************************************************************
:loop
set "fname=%2\%~n1(%cnt%)%~x1"
if exist "%fname%" set /a cnt+=1 && goto :loop
copy "%~1" "%fname%"
exit /b
::***************************************************************************************
:Explorer <file>
explorer.exe /e,/select,"%~1"
Goto :EOF
::***************************************************************************************
```

Comment: It worked good, thank you! I just don't understand some of the things in the code. Anyways, I found a way to have multiple paths by using loops and finding one at the time and put it into one variable that change after finding the next one. Not very efficient but not very complicated also.