# Batch script to look for multiple files else keep

Tags: batch-file

I'm using this batch to keep looping until I found a file. Is there a way to look for multiple files  `LookForFile= ("D:\File.txt" "D:\File1.txt" )` asking for all files to be found then end the script.. using batch similar to something below ?

```
SET LookForFile="D:\File.txt"

:CheckForFile

IF EXIST %LookForFile% GOTO FoundIt

REM If we get here, the file is not found.

REM Wait 5 seconds and then recheck.
REM If no display is needed, comment/remove the timeout line.

TIMEOUT /T 5 >nul

GOTO CheckForFile


:FoundIt

REM If you are here the file is found

ECHO Found: %LookForFile%
```

Any recommendation would be lovely thanks.

Comment: Will code continue running where at least one file is found or when all the files are found?

Comment: @MCND when all files are found .  added to question.

Comment: You can use the command `Where /?` ==> [find multiple files paths with single string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048402/find-multiple-files-paths-with-single-string/40057656#40057656)  just change `"FileName=Readme.txt"` to `"FileName=File*.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

:loop
    rem Be optimistic
    set "allFilesFound=1"

    rem Now, check. If some file is not found clean variable
    for %%a in (
        "d:\file.txt" "d:\file1.txt"
    ) do if not exist "%%~a" set "allFilesFound="

    rem If the variable is clean (it is not defined) there is 
    rem at least a missing file. Wait and check again
    if not defined allFilesFound (
        >nul 2>nul ping -n 6 localhost
        goto :loop
    )

    rem Script continue here when all files are found
    echo All files found
```